# Kernel dying when setting up SpaCy environment, have tried in virtual env but same issue. How should I fix?

Tags: python, installation, nlp, jupyter, spacy

So as mentioned my jupyter notebook kernel dies when importing SpaCy. This error started with conflicting packages and would load a much older version of Spacy which I didn't need. So I decided to uninstall the conflicting package and reinstall the latest version of Spacy. This ended up no longer having the confliction but instantly killing the kernel.

So I'm inexperienced in managing packages etc. I'm not sure if I downloaded with conda instead of pip, I may have installed with both.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by uninstalling my base python download version as well as uninstalling anaconda and only using conda-forge. I must have had a conflicting package in my base python download.

Now managing all packages only with conda and also running jupyter on VSCode.